# How to create an array of evenly spaced float values

Tags: python

I'm trying to create an array of evenly spaced float values with a step of 1e-05.

I tried this;

```
df["new_col"] = (0, len(df.index), dt)
```

Where `dt` is the time step and `df` is the original DataFrame

I understand this won't work as it needs integers, however is there another clean way to do this that avoids using loops etc?

Thanks

Comment: Use numpy's `arange` method? Like `np.arange(0, max, 1e-5)`.

Comment: Are you sure of the parens, or should it be `df["new_col"]`, and are you sure that simply assigning a mere tuple would do the trick even with integer values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some precision as you are trying to insert the resulting data in a dataframe.

Simply using [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), you can't know in advance the number of values that will be returned. This will returned a `ValueError` error if the length doesn't match that of the dataframe (which will very likely be the case if you just take a random upper bound). So you need to compute the upper bound.

You also need to take into account that the relative floating point precision could yield one extra value (e.g., if `start = 30`). So the safe thing would be to slice the output of `arange`.

```
dt = 1e-5
start = 30
df['new_col'] = np.arange(start, start+len(df)*dt, dt)[:len(df)]
```

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(7)})
dt = 1e-5
start = 30
df['new_col'] = np.arange(start, start+len(df)*dt, dt)[:len(df)]
```

output:

```
   col   new_col
0    0  30.00000
1    1  30.00001
2    2  30.00002
3    3  30.00003
4    4  30.00004
5    5  30.00005
6    6  30.00006
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NumPy's `arange` for that:

```
import numpy as np
start=1
stop=10
step=0.05
df['column_name']=np.arange(start,stop, step)
```

Make sure the number of floats is the same as the length of your df.